# how to integrate array key existence factor into a query request

Tags: php

I'm trying to filter a table based on two parameters if entered. What I'm doing here is that if text is entered into an input field attached to a column, "searchRecord" is sent to "action.php" file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#conditions_n').keyup(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    let action = 'searchRecord';
                    let conditions = $('#conditions_n').val();
                    if(conditions != '') {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "action.php",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {action:action, conditions:conditions},
                            success: function(data){
                                $('#post_list').html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                $('#modelYears_n').keyup(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    let action = 'searchRecord';
                    let modelYears = $('#modelYears_n').val();
                    if(modelYears != '') {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "action.php",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {action:action, modelYears:modelYears},
                            success: function(data){
                                $('#post_list').html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Where I want to run a SELECT query.

```
if($_POST['action'] == ('searchRecord')){
        $conditons = $_POST['conditions'];
        $modelYears = $_POST['modelYears'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM suppliers
                  WHERE (conditions LIKE '%$conditons%') AND (modelYears LIKE '%$modelYears%')";
        getData($query);
    }
```

The issue of course is that if data is entered into one field, in the action.php file, the other field is empty so I get an array key error, and the query does not work, since one of the array keys ($conditions, $modelYears) does not exist. Also when you enter data into one field the other POST request gets overwritten.

I have tried to separate these two actions, but then the table does not filter on two parameters.

So at the end of the day, I have no idea what I'm doing or how I should fix it, a hint would be nice.

Comment: Have you considered using a `FormData` object bound to the parent form and supplied within the ajax function? Your PHP however is open to sql injection - you should use a Prepared Statement!

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have not, but I will try, thank you

Comment: Instead of splitting it up into two different calls, just do one single function that fetches and sends all inputs/values. Then execute that same function when either input is changed. In your PHP, only add the conditions to your SQL if any data is set for that specific field.